# Can't Add Autolayout Constraints To UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a UIView with a container, in that container I have a UIPageViewController that will have views you can swipe through, similar to Apple's Stocks app on the iPhone.

I'm trying to go all Autolayout with this, but the UIPageViewController won't let me add Autolayout constraints.

The last line of the following code gets a "No visible @interface for 'UIPageViewController' declares the selector 'addConstraints'.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.con_pageViewController);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[conPageViewController]"
                                                               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary];
[self.pageViewControllerPortrait addConstraints:constraints];
```

However if I don't set something the UIPageViewController takes over the whole page as seen in the following image. The whole view has an aqua background, the container a pink background, the UIPageViewController has an orange background, (set in code), and the view that I want to display in the UIPageViewController is tan, (I think).

As you can see, the UIPageViewController takes the whole view, with the view it is meant to show following.

[image]

If I set the UIPageViewController's frame to the size of its container it looks like the following. I feel like if I can't add constraints to UIPageViewController that this way would be best for the long term.

```
self.pageViewControllerPortrait.view.frame = self.con_pageViewController.frame;
```

[image]

If I hardcode the frame of UIPageViewController I can get the size I want, however what I don't understand is that the container is 220px, but I need to set the UIPageViewController to a height of 284px for it to fill the container.

```
self.pageViewControllerPortrait.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 284);
```

[image]

If anyone could explain what is going on here It would be greatly appreciated.

How this looks in Interface Builder incase it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was being an idiot and had added the UIPageViewController to my view, not my container view.